# SAP Commerce Cloud with Spartacus installation error

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am with a local installation of Sap Commerce Cloud 2011 with Spartacus following the steps of https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2011/
When i execute the sentence: install.bat -r cx-for-spa

BUILD FAILED
D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:9: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\antmacros.xml:89: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\mavenTasks.xml:440: Java returned: 1

Total time: 3 seconds

> Task :recipes:cx-for-spa:createStoreFrontExt FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\CX\SCC\installer\recipes\cx-for-spa\build.gradle' line: 581
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':recipes:cx-for-spa:createStoreFrontExt'.

> external process returned non-zero exit code, command: [cmd, /c, set "ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" & set "PLATFORM_HOME=D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform" & set "ANT_HOME=D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant" & set "PATH=D:\CX\SCC\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant\bin;%PATH%" & ant createConfig -Dinput.template=develop]

I have executed those steps( sets and ant ) and repeat the install setence..but this error always appears.

Any help is welcome .. thank you very much in advance

Comment: I had faced a similar issue. Try using 1905 instead of 2011

Comment: Thx... but..at this moment i only have the 2011 release

Answer (score 0):

I did the same installation last week (Sap Commerce 2011 for Spartacus).

Question to you:

**Have you installed the jdk SapMachine 11 or 17? (17 makes trouble)**
https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/

**Have you updated the System Environment Variables of your system?**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5wJXR63g1U

**Have you comment out "Build Parallel = true" in the config file?**
C:\SapCommerce2011\installer\customconfig
In file:"build.parallel=true" => "#build.parallel=true"

KR
Nathan

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30208044)